# i18n_patterns and links in templates

Tags: django, internationalization

i actually already solved this issue, but all the solutions i've found so far are just tricky workarounds.

i'm playing with i18n_patterns and everything's working fine except links.

For instance, href="contacts" redirects users to "/en/contacts" or "/it/contatti", but in page source it remains "contacts".

For SEO optimizations purposes i'd like to see href="/en/contacts"

Is this possibile without writing code?

cheers,

Davide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the url templatetag this should be handled automatically.

```
<a href"{% url view_name %}">Link</a>
```

From django documentation:

> If localized URLs get reversed in templates they always use the
>   current language. To link to a URL in another language use the
>   language template tag.

[Read more about localized url-patterns in the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns)